# How to add multiple option in indexOf

Tags: android, spannablestring

```
int idx1 = mystr.indexOf("@");
```

how to add one more character with OR operator.
 like this

```
 mystr.indexOf("@" || "#");
```

Comment: get two index and pick minimum of those

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan hcan u tell me how would i do that??

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan This solution will return -1 if any of given character not found in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following code:

```
int minIndex =  Math.min(mystr.indexOf("@") ,mystr.indexOf("#") );
```

if you don't have one of those `char` in your String, this return `-1`.

thanks of Adnan that mention on comment

so you need

```
int idx1 = mystr.indexOf("@");
int idx2 = mystr.indexOf("#");

int minIndex;
if(idx1 >= 0 && idx2 >= 0 )
 minIndex  =  Math.min(mystr.indexOf("@") ,mystr.indexOf("#") );

else if (idx1 >= 0)
  minIndex = idx1;

else
   minIndex = idx2;
```

Comment: This solution will return -1 if any of given character not found in string.

Comment: i think user must be handle that, but thanks for your comment, i tell to user

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan  there is another problem plz help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268065/how-to-make-sapnable-with-multiple-text

Comment: Good job. Perhaps don't you think that " int minIndex " is useless because that is defined in a if statement and would not be accessible after this line? Further a lot of if conditions for a really simple task?

Comment: @Adnan  for first thing you right, i edit my post, but for second did you have any better idea?

Comment: Did you check my edited post? I replaced -1 with mystr.indexOf("@") and it is doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int idx1 = (mystr.indexOf("@")==-1)? mystr.indexOf("#"):mystr.indexOf("@");
```

If case you want the minimum index. You may go for Shayan's code snippet.

Comment: adnan i think your approach return -1 too, so what is different?

Comment: Sorry,  typo :D check it now.

Comment: @Adnan thanks for your help. can you hlp me for this quation.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268065/how-to-make-sapnable-with-multiple-text

Comment: with your code if position of @ = 20 and position of # = 5, result is 20 that completely wrong

Comment: But in post can you see anywhere that he is looking for minimum index?

Comment: He is asking for OR clause.

Comment: indexOf return minimum index, when OP want show `mystr.indexOf("@" || "#");` then he want minimum index of those

Comment: If he is really looking for it then he got his answer :) Good work

Comment: so please edit your post, because your post up vote more than my, maybe other people use your code,