# How to make spannable with multiple text?

Tags: android, spannablestring

```
String sentence="this is @part 1 and #here another and #another one @user  #newone @itsme ";

    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(addClickablePart(sentence), BufferType.SPANNABLE);


    private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb=new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    int idx1=Math.min(str.indexOf("@"),str.indexOf("#") );

    int idx2=0;
    while (idx1!=-1) {
        idx2=str.indexOf(" ", idx1) + 1;

        final String clickString=str.substring(idx1, idx2);
        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), clickString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);

        idx1=Math.min(str.indexOf("#", idx2),str.indexOf("@", idx2) );

    }

    return ssb;
}
```

its working fine for first five words but left last one (@itsme). 
it lefts only last one (no matter whats the length of string).

Comment: try log `idx1` on while statement and put log to us

Comment: @Shayan pourvatan log result     20, 38, 51, 59, -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put one condition in while statement for checking string size.

i think `idx2` in last loop is 0, because `str.indexOf()` is -1 then -1 +1 = 0.

so you check that if `idx2` is 0 then make clickable until last of size

Use following code:

```
while (idx1 != -1) {

            idx2 = sentence.indexOf(" ", idx1) + 1;

            if(idx2 == 0)  
                 idx2 = sentence.length(); // or str.lenght()-1 

            idx2 = sentence.indexOf(" ", idx1) + 1;

            final String clickString=str.substring(idx1, idx2);
            ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), clickString,
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
         }, idx1, idx2, 0);

            idx1 = FindMin(idx2+1 , sentence);
        }
```

FindMin is:

```
public int FindMin(int i2 , String mystr)
    {
        int idx1 = mystr.indexOf("@" , i2);
        int idx2 = mystr.indexOf("#" , i2);


        int minIndex;
        if(idx1 >= 0 && idx2 >= 0 )
         minIndex  =  Math.min(mystr.indexOf("@" , i2) ,mystr.indexOf("#" , i2) );

        else if (idx1 >= 0)
          minIndex = idx1;

        else
           minIndex = idx2;

        return minIndex;
    }
```

Comment: idx1 and idx2 values in while loop respectively-- 20===14
 38===26
 51===47
 59===58
 -1===67

Comment: i write one log statement, please copy that on your code and print output to me

Comment: yes, and also navigate to other page with respective id.

Comment: did you copy `Log.d("idx1 , idx2" , ""+idx1+" , "+idx2 );` to your code? what is the result ?

Comment: its 20,14   38,26   51,47   59,58  -1,67

Comment: all i want is to navigate on second page with respective id to that particular text, who has initials @ or #.  there can be multiple @ and  # .what currently i'm using is not working plz suggest me some thing.

Comment: you have a problem because my first algorithm return -1. i said use second algorithm . in last loop # is not exist and @ is 70 so min (-1 , 70) = -1

Comment: that whole concept is not correct, what if there is not any @ and only #, then nothing gona be selected because it return -1 at first time

Comment: yes, so use second algorithm. because if you use just one tag your code not work at all

Comment: but how i'll replace idx1 value inside while loop

Comment: see my Edit, use that, just put `ClickableSpan` on to that

Comment: i did that, using your last edited answer in previous question. thanks.